# Get elasticloadbalancers names with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

When I try to print the load balancers from aws I get a huge dictionary with a lot of keys, but when I'm trying to print only the 'LoadBalancerName' value I get: None, I want to print all the load balancers names in our environment how I can do it? thanks!
What I tried:

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('elbv2')
elb = client.describe_load_balancers()
Name = elb.get('LoadBalancerName')
print(Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you were handling the response object was incorrect, and you'll need to put it in a loop if you want all the Names and not just one. What you'll you'll need is this :

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('elbv2')
elb = client.describe_load_balancers()
for i in elb['LoadBalancers']:
    print(i['LoadBalancerArn'])    
    print(i['LoadBalancerName'])
```

However if your still getting none as a value it would be worth double checking what region the load balancers are in as well as if you need to pass in the use of a profile too.